# Partial Merging in GIT

Tags: git, github, merge

Please help for my below problems.
I have two branches A and B in GIT repo. Now both these branches are having two folders Folder1 and Folder2.
Now I have changed some files inside the both folders for branch B and I committed all the changes in a single commit and pushed the changes to Branch B as well. Now I want to have the changes for Folder1 from branch B to branch A, but not the changes for Folder2 from B. How can I merge B to A in GIT so only Folder1's changes from B will get merged to Folder1 of A.

Regards
Prasenjit

Comment: It is common practice to try to do atomic commits, i.e. commits only containing related changes. This does not seem to be the case here: if you want to apply only the changes from folder A to the other branch, you should have created two different commits in the first place, one containing the folder A changes and one containing the folder B changes.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the commit is `abc123`.

```
#switch to A
git checkout A

#apply abc123's changes to A but not commit them
git cherry-pick abc123 -n

#commit the changes of Folder1
git commit -- Folder1

#discard the changes of Folder2
git reset HEAD -- Folder2
git checkout -- Folder2
```